# Azure Scheduler Job: SendFailure The underlying connection was closed

Tags: asp.net, azure, ssl, iis

I have created Scheduler Job in Azure using HTTPS action to periodically ping ASP.NET Web application deployed on VM. Web application is configured with HTTPS binding using SSL certificate. I have configured IIS security using IIS Crypto 2.0 tool.

Scheduler Job fails with an error:

> Http Action - Request to host 'www.somesamplehost.com' failed: SendFailure The
> underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a
> send.

The same URL works fine when I try to access it from any browser.

Screenshot from Azure Portal:
[image: Screenshot from Azure Portal]

Comment: Please post the code that's failing?

Comment: I have added screenshot.

Comment: This can be multiple things - if you can provide your subscription Id, job collection name, job name, I can look into. You can send these info via email to me at Derek.Li@microsoft.com

Comment: Alternatively, feel free to submit a support ticket within the portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was due to SSL certificate. I have ECC SSL certificate for my Web Application and Azure Scheduler Job does not support making requests to Web Application that has that kind of certificate.

Guys from MS suggested alternative for Scheduler Job. It is a feature in Azure Portal called "Logic Apps". You can set it up in a way that it periodically makes requests to specific URL, but "Logic Apps" has much more capabilities compared to Scheduler Job.